# Why are Unity Prefab values wrong when instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a C# script on a character that holds a reference to a Prefab.

During initialization, the script runs :

```
weaponSlot = Instantiate(weaponPrefab) as Transform;
```

and sets

```
weaponSlot.parent = rightHand;
```

the prefab contains scaling information for the weapon, as well as some small rotation and position offsets for it to look correct.

When the game is run, the weapon's actual position is offset from the rightHand by a massive amount, although the rotation is preserved. The scaling is also a bit off, smaller than the prefab-ed size by roughly 40%.

Any insight on why this is happening, or even hints on what to check would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to wrap any models in an empty game object. The size, position, and orientation need to be correct under the root gameobject. When you instantiate a gameobject under a parent you need to be sure to zero-out the localPosition, and localEulerAngles (set them = Vector3.zero). You need to also set the localScale = Vector3.one.

It should look like this in the project:

Prefab (zero position, zero rotation, one scale)
->Model (correct scaling, rotation, and position)

Then you parent it.

Comment: Was using the free angelic sword 03 on unity store, the prefab had a scale of 0.02 by default, after we corrected the model and made our own prefab, everything worked as expected.

Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!